# Reference element by index in a list using Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Trying to obtain an element in a list by its index, using batch script. Here is the code:

```
@Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set acc[0]=default
set acc[1]=Account_2
set acc[2]=Account_3
set acc[3]=Account_4
set acc[4]=Account_5

if exist interator.txt (
    set /p i=<interator.txt
    echo "read: !i!"
    echo "!acc[%i%]!"
    REM start cmd /c setx AWS_PROFILE !acc[%i%]!
    REM start cmd /k python script.py
    set /A i=i+1
    (echo !i!)>interator.txt
    echo "write: !i!"
) else (
    (echo 0)>interator.txt
)
```

Output Received:

```
"read: 0"
""
"write: 1"
```

As setx requires the CMD session to be closed, for affect to take place. I am trying a different approach to automate some regular stuff.

Expected Output:

```
"read: 0"
"default"
"write: 1"
```

Answer (score 2):

```batch-file
@Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "acc[0]=default
set "acc[1]=Account_2"
set "acc[2]=Account_3"
set "acc[3]=Account_4"
set "acc[4]=Account_5"

if exist q65771965.txt (
    set /p i=<q65771965.txt
    echo "read: !i!"
    FOR %%a IN (acc[!i!]) DO (
     ECHO "!%%a!"
     echo start cmd /c setx AWS_PROFILE "!%%a!"
     echo start cmd /k python script.py
    )
    set /A i=i+1
    (echo !i!)
    echo "write: !i!"
) else (
    (echo 0)
)

GOTO :EOF
```

OK - small changes to allow this to work on my test environment:

Changed name of file from `interator.txt` to `q65771965.txt` (suits my environment)

Removed updating of data file so the modifications are shown on-screen.

Replaced `REM start` with `ECHO start` to show the `start` commands on-screen.

Subtle syntax-oriented change : Use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces.

Significant change : insert a `for` loop to transfer indirect values to a metavariable (`%%a`) and use these.

Possibly-required : I don't use `setx` much, but I've some memory of the argument's needing to be `"quoted"`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you used `echo "%acc[!i!]%"` within a codeblock. You need another layer of parsing, like `call echo "%%acc[!i!]%%"`
As an alternative, restructure your code, so the critical part isn't in a code block:

```
@Echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set acc[0]=default
set acc[1]=Account_2
set acc[2]=Account_3
set acc[3]=Account_4
set acc[4]=Account_5

if not exist interator.txt (
  (echo 0)>interator.txt
  goto :eof
)

set /p i=<interator.txt
echo "read: !i!"
echo "%acc[!i!]%"
set /A i=i+1
(echo !i!)>interator.txt
echo "write: !i!"
```

(this code is functionally identically to yours, just structured in another way)

(btw: it should probably `iterator`, not `interator` - but that's only spelling)